# How to set the permission in the final manifest

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, java-web-start

I encountered issues with JWS applications complaining that a jar is set to run in sandbox only. Looking at the generated jars, saw the the Permission is set to sandbox. I was unable to find a way to change this to all-permissions. I tried adding that to the manifest file within the project but still gets overwritten. I guess this is on recent Java versions since the old jars of the application work fine.

Any idea how to set this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it! Properties -> Application -> Web Start. Then select one of the security enabled options and set Mixed code to Trusted Only.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to set the [`security` element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html#security) of the **JNLP** file to `all-permissions` in order to gain the required permission.

Comment: jnlp already has that, but for some reason it started complaining about it recently. This is on a Snow Leopard Mac. Application started having issues after the Java release (1.6.65) and found this while looking at the issue.

Comment: Everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of either of following options.

1) Modify the code generation/jar creation logic to add `all-permissions` to the manifest.
2) If thats not possible add `<security>    <all-permissions/>   </security>` in your jnlp resource
3) Once the jar is generated, unsign, modify manifest and resign.